# dll file in html file with spring boot and angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, dll, jhipster

I'm new to Spring and Angular and I haven't deal before with dll files.
I have a webapp which is developed with C# and Angular and I have to re-develope it with Spring Boot and Angular.

So at the index.cshtml

```
@using Cockpit.ViewModels

<div id="page">

</div>
```

And Cockpit is a dll file Cockpit.dll

How can I reuse this dll file and its ViewModels in html file with Angular or Spring Boot?

And in which path should I copy the dll file?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The DLL file is a .net Library, your original Website Code is a Microsoft ASP.NET Application.

Now you want to switch to a completely different technology stack. Spring Boot is Java, right? You have to rewrite your view model.
Angular (Frontend) + Spring (Backend) uses completely different patterns compared to ASP.NET.